# Ruby: #8 on Project Euler, solution doesn't seem to work, but I feel so close

Tags: ruby, project

The problem is : 
The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are `9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832`.

> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. *What is the value of this product?*

```
sequence = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

rows = sequence.each_line("\n").to_a # Split string at each new line, convert to array
products = []
num = 1

# Split each array in rows to an array of chars, while deleting the newline element.
(0...rows.length).each do |row|
  rows[row] = rows[row].split("")
  rows[row].delete("\n")
end

# Change every element in rows to an integer.
(0...rows.length).each do |row|
  (0...50).each do |i|
   rows[row][i] = rows[row][i].to_i
  end
end

# This is where the magic happens
n = 0

while n <= 19
  row = rows[n]
 while row.length >= 13
   for i in (0...13)
     num = num * row[i]
   end
   products.push(num)
   num = 1
   row = row.drop(1)
 end
 n += 1
end

print products.max
```

The idea is to create an array of integers for each 50-digit line, and go through each of those arrays, multiplying the first 13 digits, storing each product in an array called products. After multiplying the first 13 digits, the first index of the 50-digit array gets removed, only having 49 digits, the process of multiplying the first 13 digits repeats until the array is left with only 13 or less integers, all the products being stored in products.

After that, the max number in products is printed out, which should be the greatest product of 13 adjacent digits in that sequence, 5377010688. But apparently, It's wrong. I have no idea why. Please help!

Comment: Please specify a problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think you are making things harder than they should be with this solution. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: This looks like a C code.. ruby offers a variety of tools to work with `String`s and `Array`s and you shouldn't have to use `while` or `for`

Comment: Agreed @cozyconemotel!

Comment: Ah, sorry guys. Honestly, I just got started with Ruby a few days ago. I'll take a look at the documentation and re-do this problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: I posted a possible answer, @user298519, more Ruby-like and more general. Maybe it helps you to got the idea behind Ruby. It's not easy when you start with it, because you have to change some patterns in your thinking. But things will get much better when you got the way, you may be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try to use the String methods in Ruby a bit more. Please take a look at [this page here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html).

You would reach the same results with the much simpler code here:

```
sequence = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

## This will remove all \n
seq = sequence.tr("\n","")

def multiply_arr(a)
  prod = 1
  a.each do |f|
    prod = prod * f.to_i    
  end
  prod
end


def max_product(s,n)
  max = -1
  lim = s.length - n
  (0..lim).each do |pos|
    ns = s.slice(pos,n)
    arr = ns.each_char.to_a
    prod = multiply_arr(arr)
    max = (prod > max) ? prod : max 
  end
  max
end

puts max_product(seq,4)
puts max_product(seq,13)
```

I ran it here and got the following output

```
5832
23514624000
```

As you may see, the first product is the same you got. Haven't verified the second, but this is easy for you to do.

By the way, this kind of code is much more general, indeed. Now you may write things like

```
puts max_product(seq,5)
```

and receive

```
40824
```

as an answer. Then you solved a much more general problem than 'calculate it for 4' and then 'calculate it for 13'.

By the way! If you want to know what sequence generate this max, you may easily rewrite your code to

```
def max_product(s,n)
  max = -1
  maxarr = []
  lim = s.length - n
  (0..lim).each do |pos|
    ns = s.slice(pos,n)
    arr = ns.each_char.to_a
    prod = multiply_arr(arr)
    if (prod > max) 
      max = prod
      maxarr = arr
    end
  end
  { "array" => maxarr, "prod" => max }
end
```

then you would get this

```
{"array"=>["9", "9", "8", "9"], "prod"=>5832}
{"array"=>["5", "5", "7", "6", "6", "8", "9", "6", "6", "4", "8", "9", "5"], "prod"=>23514624000}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I added something to the answer, just in case you need to know what is exactly the sequence generating this maximum product. By the way, if my answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it, ok? This will help me.

Comment: For max_product(s, n), what happens when you call product after the .each loop?

Comment: Also, what does max = (prod > max) ? prod : max do?

Comment: @user298519, max = (prod > max) ? prod : max is a "one-line-if". It evaluates the expression (prod > max). If it is true, max receives the first argument (prod). If it is false, max receives the second argument (max). Then, in the end of it max has the maximum always.

Comment: @user298519, I didn't understand your first question, about the each loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104082/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-user298519).

Answer (score 3):

You are making life much harder on yourself than you need to. Ruby has a pretty comprehensive core library (and an even more comprehensive standard library, but actually for this problem the core library is more than enough), so why not use it?

```
def max_product_subsequence(sequence, subsequence_length)
  sequence.
    gsub(/\s+/, '').                   # remove whitespace
    each_char.                         # split into characters
    map(&:to_i).                       # convert to integers
    each_cons(subsequence_length).     # sliding window of subsequences
    map {|subseq| subseq.reduce(:*) }. # map each subsequence to its product
    max                                # get the maximum
end
```

Comment: In the interest of not keeping 988 13-element arrays in memory and iterating over them a second time to get the maximum, I would change the last two lines (`map { ... }.max`) to `reduce(0) {|prev_max, subseq| [ prev_max, subseq.reduce(:*) ].max }`.

Comment: @Jordan: actually, there are a lot more processing steps one could fuse together. (Some automatically, by using an `Enumerator::Lazy`, some manually.) I'd prefer to leave such optimizations up to the OP. Once the individual steps are understood, it is fairly trivial to fuse them together, the opposite is not necessarily true.

Comment: Yes, I agree (although I personally wouldn't condense this code any further; the only other change I'd make is replacing `chars` with `each_char`). But I still think it's worth pointing out to the OP some possible improvements once they've had a chance to understand the basic logic.

Comment: Exactly the code I was going to write.  Good job showing the Ruby way.

Comment: Really good. But in this case we are dealing with a newbie. He is taking some time to understand my solution, which is much closer to his Ruby level. He will take a long time to understand this one. @JörgWMittag, even it being much better, concise and elegant. Completely Ruby-style! Congratulations!